# Why isn't Disqus Universal Code working?

Tags: javascript, redux, reactjs, disqus

I want to use it for my website, but having trouble loading it. Nothing shows up.

I tried clearing my caches and cookies, and disabling all plugins, extensions, and add-ons, but it still does not work.

Here is the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { Divider } from 'material-ui'

const styles = {
  title:{
color: 'white',
textAlign: 'left',
marginLeft: 30
  }
}

export default class TestingDisqus extends Component{
  render(){

return(
  <div>
    &nbsp;
    <div style={styles.title}>
      <font size="4">
        Testing Disqus
      </font>
    </div>
    &nbsp;
      <Divider style={{backgroundColor:'#282828'}}/>
    &nbsp;

    <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
    <script>
      (function()
          var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');

          s.src = '//testingdisqus.disqus.com/embed.js';

          s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
          (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
      })();
    </script>
    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript" rel="nofollow">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
  </div>
)
  }
}
```

Any insights would be appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In React it's best not to select and directly manipulate the DOM. React uses a virtual DOM and does the DOM manipulation for you. Also you have an IIFE in your JSX and in JSX you need to wrap all of your javascript in curly braces.

I recommend finding a React solution for this instead of trying to use vanilla JS in your JSX. Here is an open source react component that will likely solve your problem or get you started.

[React-disqus-thread](https://github.com/mzabriskie/react-disqus-thread)

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDisqusThread from 'react-disqus-thread'

// in your class you can add this:

  handleNewComment: function(comment) {
      console.log(comment.text);
  }

  render: function () {
      // and put a ReactDisqusThread in your JSX
      return (
          <ReactDisqusThread
              shortname="example"
              identifier="something-unique-12345"
              title="Example Thread"
              url="http://www.example.com/example-thread"
              category_id="123456"
              onNewComment={this.handleNewComment}/>
      );
  }  
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll give it a try. A few quick questions, can you put in any number for 'identifier' and anything for 'title', and as for the 'url' is that where the Disqus will be displayed? Lastly, where can I find the 'category_id'?

Comment: @JoMo Good questions. I'm not sure about all of them (I'm not experienced with Disqus). With a quick search I found a page on their docs explaining each variable. https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472098-javascript-configuration-variables . It looks like identifier is 'a unique identifier for each page where Disqus is present', title is 'a unique title for each page where Disqus is present', and url is 'a unique title for each page where Disqus is present'

Comment: as for category_id it looks like it may be optional 'Specify a category ID (not title). If undefined, Disqus will use the forum's default General category.' But you may need to configure a default for your forum for this to work. Otherwise there is instructions on the link in my previous comments for creating categories for your site / forum with their API. Hopefully this is enough to get things moving for you. Also if you're really stuck with ReactDisqusThread component try asking a question in their github issues. Looks like the author is very responsive.